# Unity 3D: Raycasting for gun hits

Tags: unity, raycasting, unityscript

I am having trouble understanding raycast hits in Unity3D.

I am trying to create an FPS game, so I have a gun, bullets and so on.

My script for the bullets is:

```
 var Bullet : Transform;
 var Spawn : Transform;
 var fireRate : float;

 private var nextFire : float;

 function Update ()
 {
     if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") && Time.time > nextFire)
     {
         nextFire = Time.time + fireRate;
         Shot();
     }
 }

 function Shot()
 {
     var pel = Instantiate(Bullet, Spawn.position, Spawn.rotation);
     pel.rigidbody.AddForce(transform.forward * 8000);


 }
```

It is very simple, but now I don't know how to make, that I have an object somewhere or terrain or something like that, and when I shoot, it reacts e. g. by displaying a little smog where you hit and ground parts blow up and so on.

I was searching for it on the net, but I can't find a solution. I read something about raycast, but I have no idea how to use it.

Comment: Did you have a look at some tutorials, e. g. this one: http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/physics/raycasting

Comment: no :) i wrote that I cant find anything :/ but thanks for you reply :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your projectile is going slow enough to see you probably don't want to spawn it using physics and then throw it. It's really to end up with a lot of unwanted behavior this way.

Instead, I'd use [Physics.Raycast](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) and then use the resulting [RaycastHit](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit.html) to see what you hit. In order to raycast:

```
    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out hit))
    {
        Collider target = hit.collider // What did I hit?
        float distance = hit.distance; // How far out?
        Vector3 location = hit.point; // Where did I make impact?
        GameObject targetGameObject = hit.collider.gameObject; // What's the GameObject?
    }
```

If you find that you're casting and hitting things you shouldn't, use the overloaded method call to add a `LayerMask` or if you want to hit multiple things you can instead use [Physics.RaycastAll](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.RaycastAll.html) which will return a `RaycastHit[]` and then you can iterate through the things you hit.

I know your question was worded more towards how to do the effects (like impact) but this route will also allow you to do that specifically by giving you the exact coordinates of the impact.

The only arguments I've heard against this approach are

1. Wanting to get a hint of where you're shooting. IRL this is done using [tracer rounds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracer_ammunition). In your game you might want to replicate this sort of thing using a [TrailRenderer](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TrailRenderer.html).
2. Wanting bullets to be affected by gravity and wind. That's not something raycasting can do. I still wouldn't instantiate a bullet GameObject and throw it with force. I'd probably recommend in this case actually calculating the trajectory yourself and then you'd have to manually do some sort of casting.

Comment: thanks :) ok so if I understand :) Raycast is method, which gives you object, that you hit, its distance, so it gives you coordinates of that impact, right? :) sooo if my bullet hit gameobject, it gives me coordinates of that impact? edit: i have "use gravity" on my bullets

Comment: A big point in the post was to NOT use bullets.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't use raycast you could just do something like

```
explosionclone = Instantiate(explosion,this.gameObject.position, Quaternion.identity);
```

If that was attached to the bullet prefab it would spawn the explosion at hit point, as the bullet already knows its position =)

If you want only explosions on walls, tag your walls - 'walls'
then use:

```
function OnCollisionEnter (col : Collision)
{
    if(col.gameObject.tag == "walls")
    {
        explosionclone = Instantiate(explosion,this.gameObject.position,
        Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```